# compatibility error in imported android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have imported an android project, here I took project from another system . In that system components of layouts are visible properly . When I import it on my system, the components designed in layouts are not visible properly . How to solve this pls help me . Thanks in advance . .

Answer (score 1):

Try to `Clean` the project. Second option would be to `restart the eclipse`...

Comment: no . . , I tried both , it doesnt work . .

Comment: ya not only for me . . for my friends too . .

Comment: Which option you are using to import project in eclipse? General -> Existing project into workspace or Android -> Existing android code into workspace?

Comment: General->Existing project